# Eclipse Juno C++ error: Program "g++" not found in PATH

Tags: 12.04, eclipse, c++, g++

I installed the newest Eclipse Juno manually (not through software center nor apt-get), and then install Eclipse CDT from the help > install new software menu.

However, when I try to compile a simple C++ code it show errors like **Program "g++" not found in PATH.**

I tried g++ from terminal and it worked just fine. Anyone know where the problem might be?

Comment: You should set up path for g++ in `Project -> Properties` or `Window -> Preferences->`'sth like Eclipse CDT'(I'm sorry that I give so less info , I never worked with CDT, but I had the same with Python 3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install the `build-essential`

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

after installing this, open a terminal, and type
`g++` (hit enter)
if it says there is no input, then you got your g++

even after you installed this, you could still have problems with eclipse cdt
so I really recommend Netbeans, click [here](http://netbeans.org/downloads/).

All you need to do is download Netbeans to your computer, say it's in your `Download` folder

`sudo chmod +x your_download_netbeans.sh`

then
`./your_download_netbeans.sh`

Because you already installed Eclipse on you computer, so I think you've already got jdk installed.

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you install build-essential, you have g++. In path too. And you should always download Eclipse and Netbeans from their respective websites.

Answer (score 4):

Annoying problem, no answers to be found...
I added the path variable to environment variables in `Window/preferences/build/environment`
It works since.

Answer (score 0):

The g++ compiler is in the /usr/bin directory. The "sources.mk" file is generated and contains the path to the compiler. The path is not being generated. I edited the file to add the path to the C++_SRCS parameter. Ignore the do not edit at the top.

C++_SRCS := /usr/bin

Make sure that you've done the "install essential" as described above.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I solved it by:

1. Installing **g++ The GNU C++ compiler** using Ubuntu Software Center
2. Changing in: Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Discovery -> CDT GCC Build in Complier  Settings [Shared]
   from: `${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"`
   to: `/usr/bin/${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I solved it by:

Installing g++ The GNU C++ compiler using Ubuntu Software Center

Changing in: `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `C/C++` -> `Build` -> `Settings` -> `Discovery` -> `CDT GCC Build in Complier Settings [Shared]`

from:

```
${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"
```

to:

```
/usr/bin/${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"
```