# Installing Eclipse with Java and CDT

Tags: installation, java, eclipse, c++

Long story short, my computer got a virus yesterday and when I tried to re-image the computer, I accidentally wiped out Windows. While I'm waiting for a Windows 8 OEM disc to get here in the mail, I decided to tinker around in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I've been teaching myself a little C++ lately, and on Windows, for lack of a better option, I just was using Visual Studio C++ Express 2010. Obviously, I couldn't use this IDE on Ubuntu, so I tried to install Eclipse. I wanted it to be able to compile both Java and C++ applications, so first I installed `eclipse-java-juno-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz` from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ (It was the 3rd from the top.) Everything compiled and ran just fine in the Java perspective.

When I tried to install the C/C++ Developer Tools, things started going awry. First I tried installing the plugin from the `Help > Add New Software...` menu. It said everything downloaded correctly, and after restarting Eclipse, my hello world program failed with the error `Launch failed. Binary not found.` This error was really cryptic, and didn't even give me an error number, so I tried removing Eclipse and re-installing Eclipse again, this time the option with CDT built in: `eclipse-cpp-juno-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz`, again from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ .

This time when everything started up, I tried running a hello world program, but it underlined all of my `std`'s and `cout`'s with an error saying something was unresolved (I don't remember what it said exactly because I have since taken the CDT version back off and re-installed the Java version, which still works fine.

Also, at some point along the way I was having this error: [Eclipse Juno C++ error: Program "g++" not found in PATH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171834/eclipse-juno-c-error-program-g-not-found-in-path) which I never managed to solve before I uninstalled back to just having Java support.

I could really use some help here, and if you could explain some of the in-depth Linux jargon that you use, that'd be great too as I've only been using Ubuntu for less than 36 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure why this worked, when I went through the C++ project wizard and got to the final slide reading "Configure the Cross GCC path and prefix", I left the prefix blank and set the path to `/usr/bin/g++`. Now everything seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the c++ compiler.

in the Ubuntu Software Center, install the package called "build-essential", it should pull automatically all you need.

Regards